# How make partial component which share one logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I created baseModal for my project, which takes arguments like header , body, footer as props.

The problem is, when i have actual modal, which should have searchbar in header , and body that will response to input in Header.
Is it a way to create Header and Body components, that will share same logic

i have tried this:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useThisModal() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const list = ["1", "12", "3"];
  const [sorted, setSorted] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleSearch = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value || "");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSorted(prev => list.filter((item) => item.startsWith(search)));
    
  }, [search]);

  return { sorted, handleSearch };
}

export function Header() {
  const { handleSearch } = useThisModal();
  return <input onChange={handleSearch} type="text" />;
}

export function Body() {
  const { sorted } = useThisModal();
  return <div>{sorted.map((item) => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}</div>;
}
```

but in that case i create new instance of hook in each component...
the way i have came to is just use react context, but maybe someone know easier way or more concise

Answer (score 0):

I will propose two other options, however note that using react context is also a valid solution.

Note: Ultimately, in small components it doesn't really matter that much. However, when you need to share state and functionality in a more complex manner and with a deeper component tree, I like using react context, but something like `Redux` can be a valid solution too. Recommand you search on that.

**1. Using Props**

You create a single instance of the states and functions, and pass them as props to the `Body` and `Header`.

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useThisModal() {
  // All of your "useThisModal" logic, etc.

  return { sorted, handleSearch };
}

export function Header({ handleSearch }) {
  return <input onChange={handleSearch} type="text" />;
}

export function Body({ sorted }) {
  return <div>{sorted.map((item) => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}</div>;
}

// some parent component

function ParentComponent() {
  { sorted, handleSearch } = useThisModal()
  return (
    <div>
      <Header handleSearch={handleSearch} />
      <Body sorted={sorted} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**2. Combine into a single component**

Since this is a small component, you can collect the JSX from the `Body` and `Header` components, and merge into a single component. At this point, at least, this seems to be more clean. sometimes, over separating components into subcomponents can create issues.

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useThisModal() {
  // All of your "useThisModal" logic, etc.

  return { sorted, handleSearch };
}

function ParentComponent() {
  { sorted, handleSearch } = useThisModal()
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleSearch} type="text" />     
      <div>{sorted.map((item) => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}</div> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is concise, and since the two are very much related, it is logicall in this case to put them together.

**3. Context \ state management solution like Redux**

As I said, when larger component trees occur in your project, this would probably be the best choice.